# What is the best way to compress postgres database dump file?

Tags: postgresql

I have large databases which im dumping with pg_dump and I need to make dump file smaller.
What is the best way to compress this postgres database dump file?

Answer (score 2):

`pg_dump` comes with compression feature built-in:

- `-Z 0..9`
- `--compress 0..9`

> Specify the compression level to use. Zero means no compression. For the custom archive format, this specifies compression of individual table-data segments, and the default is to compress at a moderate level. For plain text output, setting a nonzero compression level causes the entire output file to be compressed, as though it had been fed through gzip; but the default is not to compress. The tar archive format currently does not support compression at all.

There are 9 levels of compression - higher the level, higher the compression. 0 means no compression.

```
pg_dump [connection-option...] --compress=9 [dbname]
```

for maximum compression.

Comment: @masonrye if you believe my answer was helpful, you should consider [accepting it](https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) so the question won't stay as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

`xz` compresses data better than `gzip`. Running `xz -6 <dumpfile>` will compress the database dump with maximum compression.

Comment: "Better" is an understatement, actually. I've seen ratios of 1:100 for some dumps.

Answer (score 0):

there's also parallel gzip https://zlib.net/pigz/ for when you really need to maximize all your cores on a big compression job.